# Hypergeometric formulas for the j-function

Tags: special-functions, modular-forms, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-functions

Given the *[j-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html)* $j(\tau)$ and *[elliptic lambda function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html)* $\lambda(\tau)$. Define,

$$g = -1+2\frac{\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},1,\,\lambda(2\tau)\big) }{\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},1,\,\lambda(\tau)\big) }$$

then,

$$j(\tau) = \frac{4^4(g^4-g^2+1)^3 }{(g^4-g^2)^2}\tag{1}$$

**Question**: *Any other formula that uses $\,_2F_1\big(a,b;c;z\big)$ for other $a,b,c$?*

$\color{blue}{Edit}$: (In response to ccorn's answer.)

For ***any non-zero constant*** $N(N-1728)\neq0$, one can solve the following two equations,

$$N = \frac{(x^2+10x+5)^3}{x}\tag{2}$$

$$N = \frac{-(r^{20} - 228r^{15} + 494r^{10} + 228r^5 + 1)^3}{r^5(r^{10} + 11r^5 - 1)^5}\tag{3}$$

for unknowns $x,r$ as,

$$x = \frac{-125r^5}{r^{10}+11r^5-1}$$

where,

$$r = \frac{N\,^{-11/60}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac{31}{60},\tfrac{11}{60},\tfrac{6}{5},\tfrac{1728}{N}\right)}{N\,^{1/60}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac{19}{60},\tfrac{-1}{60},\tfrac{4}{5},\tfrac{1728}{N}\right)} = \frac{(N-1728)^{-11/60}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac{41}{60},\tfrac{11}{60},\tfrac{6}{5},\tfrac{1728}{1728-N}\right)}{(N-1728)^{1/60}\,_2F_1\left(\tfrac{29}{60},\tfrac{-1}{60},\tfrac{4}{5},\tfrac{1728}{1728-N}\right)}$$

The eqns (2) and (3) are the *Jacobi sextic* and *icosahedral equation*, respectively, both of which do not have a solvable Galois group. (Eq. (1) has a solvable group.)

The utility of the question is then it finds an equation, *with one free parameter $N$* (the special case $N = j(\tau)$ being only a subset), that can be solved in terms of $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ where $z$ is a function of $N$. (This also  implies the general quintic, via the Jacobi sextic, is solvable in terms of $r$.)

So it would be nice to find more polynomial examples like (1), but has a higher degree.

Comment: All but one of them involve $a,b = 1/2, 1/2$. My question is about ***other*** $a,b$.

Comment: Yes, my question was explicit for other $a,b,c$, (not the argument $z$). I believe one can also find for $a,b = 1/3,2/3$ and $a,b =1/4,3/4$ (which probably implies another $z$ as well).

Answer (score 4):

The following is an too-long-for-a-comment remark of mine to the original question.
It seems outdated now.

Sorry, I do not get the point of this question.

In your example, $\lambda$ is a modular function for some subgroup of the full modular group, and therefore $j$ and $\lambda$ fulfill some bivariate polynomial equation.
In fact, $j$ can be expressed as a rational function of $\lambda$.
Plumbing hypergeometrics in such a simple relation looks like an *obfuscated math contest* to me.
In particular, the given example obfuscates that
$$g=k'=\sqrt{1-\lambda}$$

So probably my two cents here will not be able to assist your quest.
Of course, I could provide another obfuscated math example:
$$j=\gamma_3^2\left(\frac{{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{5}{12};1;\frac{12^3}{\gamma_2^3}\right)}{{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{7}{12};1;-\frac{12^3}{\gamma_3^2}\right)}\right)^{12}$$
where $\gamma_2$, $\gamma_3$ are
[Weber functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeberFunctions.html).
If $\tau+m$ is in the full modular group's fundamental domain
for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$,
the numerator in the fraction is $\sqrt[4]{E_4}$,
and the denominator is $\sqrt[6]{E_6}$,
where $E_4=\gamma_2\eta^8$ and $E_6=\gamma_3\eta^{12}$
are [Eisenstein series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EisensteinSeries.html)
and $\eta$ is the
[Dedekind eta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindEtaFunction.html).
This thing just obfuscates
$$j=\gamma_2^3=\gamma_3^2+12^3$$
Therefore I do not see the point of such jugglings.

The theorem that relates modular forms with functions like ${}_2F_1$ is given,
for example, in

1. Don Zagier: Elliptic modular forms and their applications.
   In: Kristian Ranestad (ed.): The 1-2-3 of modular forms. Springer 2008,
   [DOI: 10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0).

It implies that a weight-$1$ modular form (in the wider sense, that is,
with respect to subgroups of the full modular group,
or with a multiplier system) fulfills an ordinary second-order
linear differential equation **if** the independent variable of that equation
is chosen to be a suitable modular function.
Often, the differential equation turns out to be the hypergeometric one,
and with a proper handling of initial conditions, the modular form can be
expressed *locally* in terms of ${}_2F_1$, whose main argument
is then necessarily some modular function.

The key point here is that the main argument of ${}_2F_1$, let us name it $t$,
must itself be a modular function and thus have weight zero.
But then $j$ and $t$ are algebraically related over $\mathbb{C}$.
Therefore, I expect every expression of $j$ in terms of ratios of ${}_2F_1$
to be just obfuscations of a simpler algebraic relation.
In some cases, it may serve as an illustration of hypergeometric transformations
though.

Comment: The original motivation in it weak form was to determine if $j$ can be expressed in terms of $\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ for some function $z$.  It can be but, as pointed out by Balarka, any argument $z$ seems to have a polynomial relationship with $j$. In its strong form then, one can specify the additional constraint that $j$ and $z$ should not be algebraically related over $\mathbb{C}$. I believe that there are also for $\,_2F_1(1/3,2/3;1;t)$ and $\,_2F_1(1/4,3/4;1;t)$ but, as you mentioned, these probably will involve $t$ algebraically similar (but not identical) to $\lambda$.

Comment: If there turns out to be anything like that, I would find that very interesting myself. It might imply that modular forms can fulfill *linear* ODEs over variables that are not modular functons. However, the usual way that makes ${}_2F_1$ appear requires modular functions and thereby seems to enforce an algebraic relation, so I'm skeptic.

Comment: ccorn, I've added an edit. I hope you can see why I find  polynomial relations involving $j$ can be quite fruitful.  :)

Comment: Thanks. To pre-empt comments/answers similar to mine, I let it stand. In case I find something helpful, I'll edit of course.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Back to the topic: The theorem I mentioned has an **if**, not an **iff**, so I do not have a proof that no ${}_2F_1$ expressions for $j$ exist that are not obfuscations of algebraic relations. I just do not *expect* them to exist, so I have gone out on a limb and stated that. By the way, an answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171589) might bring us one step further.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following relation

> $$ _2F_1\left( 1/2,1/2,1, x  \right)= \frac{2}{\pi} K(\sqrt{x}).  $$

where $K(x)$ is the [Complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) and $_2F_1$ is the hypergeometric function.

Comment: Yes. However, I think there should also be formulas using ratios of $\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{2}{3},1,\,z\big)$ or $\,_2F_1\big(\tfrac{1}{4},\tfrac{3}{4},1,\,z\big)$ though I'll need some time to find them.