# Modular forms and the Roger-Ramanujan identities: How??

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, number-theory

I've been studying Bressoud's paper "An easy proof of the Rogers-Ramanujan Identities" where he proves the R.R. identity:

$$\sum_{n \geq0}\frac{q^{n^2}}{(1-q) \cdots(1-q^n)}= \prod_{n \geq0}\frac{1}{(1-q^{5n+1})(1-q^{5n+4})}$$

Apparently the right hand side becomes modular when corrected by the term $q^{{-1}/{60}}$.

This seems rather arbitrary to me so I'm seeking an explanation where this may come from. Is there something more behind it? A greater context for instance?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Dedekind eta-function? $$\eta(z)=q^{1/24}\prod(1-q^n)$$ is a modular form of weight one-half. There's lots of material on eta, and maybe if you work out where the $q^{1/24}$ comes from, you'll be able to apply it to your question. Start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function

Comment: I know it but I didn't find anything promising.

Comment: Well, I suspect that if you find a proof somewhere that $\eta$ is a modular form, then you'll see where in the proof the $q^{1/24}$ is needed, and that will tell you why the $q^{-1/60}$ is needed in the other. And lots of places have proofs of the $\eta$ fact. And then maybe when you have figured it out, you can come back to post the explanation as an answer.

Comment: Seems reasonable, I'll give it a try! Thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How exactly does the modularity of $\eta(\tau)$ help with this question?

Comment: @Dzoooks, without the $q^{1/24}$, $\eta$ wouldn't be modular. So understanding why $\eta$ is modular involves seeing where the $q^{1/24}$ comes from. My thought was that having seen where the $q^{1/24}$ comes from would give OP at least a hint as to where the  $q^{-1/60}$ comes from in the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Understanding $\eta(\tau)$ has little to do with why the product sides are modular forms; as Somos' answer demonstrates, they are basically $\theta$-funtions.

Comment: @Dzoooks Specifically they are Theta constants with characteristic. Also, my answer shows how the $\eta$ function is related to the $G$ function.

Comment: @Dzoooks, I don't follow. $\prod(1-q^n)$ isn't a modular form; $\eta=q^{1/24}\prod(1-q^n)$ is. If you understand why, doesn't that give you a head start on understanding why $\prod1/((1-q^{5n+1})(1-q^{5n+4}))$ isn't but $q^{-1/60}\prod1/((1-q^{5n+1})(1-q^{5n+4}))$ is?

Comment: On a more unrelated note: I can't assess the correctness/quality of the given answer - I've never touched modular forms since the student seminar 3 years ago. This means I won't be able to accept the answer. What should I do at this point?

Comment: @noctusraid My advice is accept my answer and upvote it. You an look at my history of answering questions about modular forms and related topics here on MSE and on MathOverflow. My contributions to the OEIS. In my answer I quote relevant sources in great detail. What kind of answers were you expecting?

Comment: See related : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/671348/72031

Answer (score 2):

The R-R identity you mention in your question is one of a pair and together they are part of a fascinating story told by William Duke, [*Continued Fractions and Modular Functions*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-05-01047-5), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 42 (2005), 137-162. On page 143 he writes (**NOTE:**  $q = e(\tau) := e^{2\pi i\tau})$

> The theta constant with characteristic
>    $[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}]\in\mathbb{R}^2$
>   is defined by
>
> $ \quad\quad\quad\quad\theta[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}](\tau)=
> \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e(\frac12(n+\frac{\epsilon}2)^2\tau
> +\frac{\epsilon'}2(n+\frac{\epsilon}2))$
>
> for $\tau\in\mathcal{H}.$
>   It satisfies the following basic properties for $\ell,m,N\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $N$ positive $\textrm{[FK pp. 72-77]}$:
>
> $ (4.3)\quad\quad\quad \theta[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}](\tau) =
> e(\mp\frac{\epsilon m}2)
> \theta[^{\,\pm\epsilon+2\ell}_{\pm\epsilon'+2m}](\tau) \\
> (4.4)\quad\quad\quad \theta[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}](\tau) =
> \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \theta[^{\frac{\epsilon+2k}N}_{N\epsilon'}]
> (N^2\tau).$
>
> It also satisfies for
>    $(^{a\, b}_{c\, d})\in \textrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$
>   the fundamental transformation law $\textrm{[FK Thm 1.11, p. 81]}$:
>
> $ (4.5)\quad\quad\quad
>  \theta[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}](\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d})
>  = \kappa\sqrt{c\tau+d}\,\theta
> [^{a\epsilon+c\epsilon'-ac}_{b\epsilon+d\epsilon'+bd}](\tau)$
>
> where
>
> $\quad\quad\quad\kappa = e(-\frac14(a\epsilon+c\epsilon')bd-\frac18(
> ab\epsilon^2+cd\epsilon'^2+2bc\epsilon\epsilon'))\kappa_0,$
>
> with $\kappa_0$ and eighth root of unity depending only on the matrix $(^{a\, b}_{c\, d}).$ The value of $\kappa_0$ is fixed by
>   choosing the argument of the square root to be in $[0,\pi).\,$
>   In particular we have $\textrm{[FK, p. 86]}$
>
> $(4.6)\quad\quad\quad 
> \theta[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}](\tau+1)=
> e(-\frac{\epsilon}4(1+\frac{\epsilon}2))\theta[^{\quad\epsilon}
> _{\epsilon+\epsilon'+1}](\tau)$
>
> and
>
> $(4.7)\quad\quad\quad
>  \theta[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}](\frac{-1}\tau)=
> e(-\frac18)\sqrt{\tau}e(\frac{\epsilon\epsilon'}4)\theta
> [^{\,\,\epsilon'}_{-\epsilon}](\tau).$
>
> Additional transformation formulas invoked later in the text are
>   given in Appendix A. we also have the product formula
>    $\textrm{[FK, p. 141]}$:
>
> $ (4.8)\quad \theta[^{\,\epsilon}_{\epsilon'}](\tau) \!=\! e(\frac{\epsilon\epsilon'}4)
> q^{\frac{\epsilon^2}8} \!\prod_{n\ge 1} (1\!-\!q^n)
> (1\!+\!e(\frac{\epsilon'}2)q^{n-\frac{1+\epsilon}2})
> (1\!+\!e(\frac{-\epsilon'}2)q^{n-\frac{1-\epsilon}2}),$
>
> which follows from the Jacobi triple product identity.
>
> $\quad$ A short calculation using $(4.1)$ and $(4.8)$ shows that
>
> $ (4.9) \quad\quad\quad r(\tau) = e(-\frac1{10})\frac
>  {\theta[^{3/5}_{\,\,1}](5\tau)}{\theta[^{1/5}_{\,\,1}](5\tau)}. $

**N.B.:** In the infinite product in $(4.8)$ the $\frac{\epsilon'}2$ and $-\frac{\epsilon'}2$ should be swapped.

The reciprocal of the right side of the R-R equation corresponds to the numerator of equation $(4.9)$ of the Duke article but not exactly. What I mean is that the [theta constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_constant) has both an 
infinite sum and an infinite product expansion. As a special case of this result we have the equation

$$ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\!(-1)^n q^{(10n+3)^2} \!=\!
q^9 \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1\!-\!q^{200n})
(1\!-\!q^{200n-160})(1\!-\!q^{200n-40}) \tag{1}$$

The Wikipedia article [Rogers-Ramanujan identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_identities#Modular_functions) states that

> If $\,q=e^{2\pi i\tau},\,$ then $\,q^{-1/60}G(q)\,$ and
>   $\,q^{11/60}H(q)\,$ are modular functions of $\,\tau.$

Now, by definition of $\,G(q)\,$ we have
$$ 1/G(q) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{5n-4})(1-q^{5n-1}) \tag{2}$$
and therefore we immediately have
$$ 1/G(q^{40}) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{200n-160})(1-q^{200n-40}). \tag{3}$$
Comparing this with equation $(1)$ we now have
$$ q^9/G(q^{40})\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{200n}) =
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} (-1)^n q^{(10n+3)^2}. \tag{4}$$
The infinite product on the left side is the [Dedekind $\eta$
function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) missing a factor of $q^{200/24}=q^{25/3}.$ When we supply the missing factor, the power of $q$ on the left side is now 
$\,q^{9-25/3}=q^{2/3}.\,$ Now $\,q^{2/3}/G(q^{40})\,$ is a modular function and therefore so is $\,q^{1/60}/G(q) \,$ and 
$\,q^{-1/60}G(q)\,$ which answers your question.

**P.S.** I have found a very brief reference that may answer your question.
In Bruce C. Berndt, *Ramanujan's Notebooks, Part IV*, page 285 is written:

> McIntosh [1] has improved $(8.3)$ by proving that, as $q$ tends to $1-,$
>     $$ \log\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{q^{n^2}}{(q)_n}\right) =
>  -\frac1{\log q} \frac{\pi^2}{15} -\frac12\log\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}2\right)    + \frac{\log q}{60} + E_1(q), $$
>     where $E_1(q)$ is exponentially small. The small error term arises from $(0.1)$
>     and the transformation formula for the infinite product.

A little further on is this

> By setting $\,b=c=1\,$ in Entry 7 and using McIntosh's further work, we
>   find that, as $\,q\,$ tends to $1-$,
>   $$ \log\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{q^{n(n+1)}}{(q)_n}\right) =
>  -\frac1{\log q} \frac{\pi^2}{15} -\frac12\log\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}2\right) - \frac{11\log q}{60}+ E_2(q), $$
>   where $\,E_2(q)\,$ is exponentially small.

The coefficient of $\,\log q\,$ is why you need $\,q^{-1/60}\,$ in the
1st case and $\,q^{11/60}\,$ in the 2nd.

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned somewhere that $e(x)$ means $e^{2\pi ix}$.

Comment: Just a question: what fields of math do I have to study/what classes to take to understand some of this? I know it might be a very shallow question, but I hope it can be answered somehow

Comment: @KKZiomek Hard to give a good answer. You should have a familiarity with Ramanujan and Jacobi theta functions. This can come from studying some of Ramanujan's related work and studying several examples. You can read my essay "A multisection of q-series" for an introduction. Ask questions here on MSE as you go along....