# Inverting the modular $J$ function

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Klein's modular function $J(z)$ is defined and studied 
in e.g. Apostol's book Modular functions and Dirichlet
series in number theory.

Certain specific evaluations are available, for example,

$$J(i) = 1$$

Additionally, it is known that $J(z)$ takes on all complex
values.

Question: Can one solve for that $z$ in the fundamental domain

(either explicitly or numerically) which satisfies $J(z) = \mathrm{i}$?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for help writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for help formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: @ZevChonoles: Missing action from the OP, so I have done the editing now.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible. Here's the way to do it: choose your favorite elliptic curve $E/\mathbf C$ with $j(E) = i$. For example, the curve

$$y^2 +xy = x^3 -36(j-1728)^{-1}x - (j-1728)^{-1}$$

has $j(E)=j$ for $j \neq 0, 1728$ (so, just plug $j=i$). Compute the periods $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. Then $\tau = \omega_2/\omega_1$ satisfies $j(\tau)=i$.

Comment: Hmm, this is something out-of-the-box! +1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the *[inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Inverse_and_special_values)* of the $j$-invariant can be expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function. Since,

$$j(\tau) = 1728J(\tau)\tag{1}$$

we can solve for $\tau$ as,

$$\tau = i\frac{{}_2F_1(1/6, 5/6; 1; 1-\alpha)}{{}_2F_1(1/6, 5/6; 1; \alpha)}\tag{2}$$

where $\alpha$ is any root of the quadratic,

$$4\alpha(1-\alpha)=\frac{1}{J(\tau)}\tag{3}$$

Since your post is about $J(\tau) = i$, plugging that into (3), solving for $\alpha$, then plugging either root to (2), we find both,

$$\tau \approx  0.199329+0.7783729 i$$

$$\tau \approx -0.308752+1.2056644 i$$

yield

$$J(\tau) = i$$

Having numerically determined $\tau$, I then tried *Mathematica*'s *Recognize* function to see if it had a closed-form, but $\tau$ does not seem to be an algebraic number of deg $< 8$.

Comment: +1 for the standardized notation. Remark: The second solution for $\tau$ is the sought one, as it is in the fundamental domain. The other one is $-1/\tau$.

Comment: Considering the simplicity of $J(\tau) = i$, I first considered that $\tau$ might be algebraic. But it doesn't seem to be. However, perhaps it still has a closed-form in terms of maybe gamma functions and the like.

Comment: I have tried Pari/GP's integer relation algorithms on $\left(X, \ln 2, \ln 3, \ln\pi, \ln\Gamma(1/6)\right)$ with $X\in\{\Re\ln\tau,\ln\Re\tau\}$ with $200$ bits precision, no hit. But probably $\alpha$ should be mixed in as well.

Comment: I also tried the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) by using the absolute value of $\tau$, as well as its $\Re$ part. No hit also. By the way, do you know the command for this online [Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) to calculate the Galois group?

Comment: [I hope this helps](http://www.math.wayne.edu/answers/magma2.10/htmlhelp/text701.htm)

Comment: From [Zudilin's MO comment](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28385): *Schneider proved that the values of the modular invariant at non-CM points are transcendental*. But then $\tau$ should have degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @BalarkaSen: That's it: If $\tau$ and $j(\tau)$ are algebraic, then $\tau$ is a CM point. We have to conclude here that $\tau$ is transcendental.

Comment: @BalarkaSen: Indeed. (Besides: Typo: $j(\tau)=1728\mathrm{i}$ here). Thanks for the refresher!