# When the value of modular $j$ function is cubic number

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-function

It seems to be well known that when the class number of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ is one, the value of modular [$j$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html) at $\mathbb{Z}$ basis of integer ring of $K$ is cubic number.

But I couldn't find the available proof. I'll appreciate if someone tell me the proof or paper.

Comment: Do you have a link to such a statement? I find the [modular $J$-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438436/inverting-the-modular-j-function) in other contexts, and in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#Special_values), but no such statement right now.

Comment: I found it now [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html), with references. This is for $d=-1, -2, -3, -7, -11, -19, -43, -67, -163$.