# power series expression of theta function

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, special-functions, modular-forms

Denote $f(z)=\theta_3(z)^2$, where $\theta_3(z)=\theta(z/2), \theta(z)=\sum_n q^{n^2}$ are Jacobi's $\theta$-functions.

And $\lambda(z)=\left( \frac{\theta_2(z)}{\theta_3(z)}\right)^4$ is the Legendre modular function, where $\theta_2(z)=\sum_n q^{({n+1/2})^2}$

There is a power series expression

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{\lambda(z)}{16}\right)^n$$

How to get the expression?

Comment: the coefficients of $f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n \lambda(z)^n$ are given by $\int_{\lambda^{-1}(C)} \frac{f(z)}{\lambda(z)^{n+1}}\lambda'(z)dz$ where $\lambda^{-1}(C)$ is a contour enclosing $i\infty$, depending on the Fourier coefficients of $1/\lambda(z)$ and $\lambda'(z)$

Comment: Shouldn't the binomial coefficient be squared? Then this is essentially a hypergeometric series. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118647). In fact, that series gives the elliptic integral $\theta_3^2=\frac{2}{\pi}K(k)$ where $\lambda=k^2$. Cf. [DLMF 19.5](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.5).